# parsley - hide/show block based on value of a li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parsley.js

I have a form and i am using parsley for validation:

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="" id="credirentierform" data-parsley-validate>
     <div name="sub_part" style="display: none">
         <input id="firstname" name="firstname" required/>
     </div>
     <div name="sub_part" style="display: none">
          <input id="lastname" name="lastname" required/>
     </div>
  </form>
  <a onclick="$('#credirentierform').submit()" href="javascript:;">
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#credirentierform').parsley().subscribe('parsley:form:validated', function (formInstance) {
        var searchvalue="Erreur";   
        $("div[name='sub_part']").each(function() {
                if ($(this).html().indexOf("Erreur") >-1){
                    this.style="";
                }
                else {
                    this.style="none";
                };
        });
  });
});
```

Basically, at the submission of the form Parsley will add the following:

```
<li class="parsley-required">Erreur</li>
```

My query code is supposed to go through each div with `name="sub-part"` and if Erreur is found, the `style="block"` otherwise `style="none"`. However, it does not behave that way.
It seems that my code does look into the entire page and not within the section defined by `name="sub-part"`.

What am i missing?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like using $(this) within the first result set to find your subsequent matches in a non global fashion?

```
$(this).find("div[name='sub_part']").each(function() {
   if ($(this).html().indexOf("Erreur") >-1){
     this.style="";
   }
   else {
      this.style="none";
   };
});
```

Comment: Thanks but it actually does not work (nothing is happening). any idea?

Comment: Have you tried outputting the results of each jQuery selector to see if your queries are matching or even returning results? You need to make sure that you are operating on the correct items every step of the way.

For Example:
$(this).find("div[name='sub_part']").each(function() {
  console.log('TESTING SELECTOR OUTPUT -------------------------');
  console.log($this);
});